# AngularJS architecture: mono-repo or multi-repo

Tags: javascript, angularjs, architecture

I am doing some research into the possibility of code splitting a huge monolith SPA (AngularJS) into multiple repositories. Whether we should do it or not? The benefits and pitfalls.

**The Idea:**

The application consists of multiple features (user management, analytics, event management) which are made as individual `angular.module`.

The idea was to split these different modules into their own repository and have some kind of master repository which would put all the pieces together before deploying.

**The reason**

Our application is huge now and will only get bigger. Also, the number of developers working on it is increasing.

Other reasons:

- More manageable and maintainable - only feature specific files available
- Easier to update to newer version of angular - one repo at a time

**Findings**

I have read that [micro frontend](https://micro-frontends.org/) architecture is becoming a more and more popular way of structuring big applications.

On the other hand, this will scatter files making it more difficult when fx. refactoring shared modules. It also appears that fx. Facebook and Google have mono repo.

After several days of research, I'm still torn. I see advantages with both, mono repository and multiple repositories.

I have also looked into `git submodule` as a way to "import" the features into the main repository. This is my least favorite options though. Also, I've never heard of `git submodule` before now so if anybody has some experience in that area please feel free to jump in.

Finally, the most important question: Is it even possible to have one AngularJS application split into multiple repositories?

Additional information:
[Microservices: Mono repo vs. multiple repositories](https://jaxenter.com/microservices-mono-repo-vs-multiple-repositories-130148.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handling Monolith Code Bases

I have had the same issue the internal conflict that comes with it. The best answer I have found is this. "You and your team are the best people to answer this question." I know this goes against the hype of things like Micro FrontEnds will rule the world but it is the truth. This explains why some people use monoliths and are really successful like Facebook and others have the opposite outcome go with Micro Frontends and then become successful.

The only real problem in managing large amounts of code is a human problem not a technical problem. So this is a social issue. Sure, technical things change with this decision but in the end of the day you are just changing the human interaction between programmers and this code base.

So why is your team the most qualified to make this decision. You know the social dynamics of your team and corporate culture better then the rest of us.

I asked myself these types of questions when I was making this decision.

How does the team work together?

How is your team trained?

How flexible is your team?

How clear and open is the communication between teams and team members?

I would answer these types of questions and continue using case studies like Facebook which proved size of the team on a monolith does not really matter but how you work together on that monolith does and make the decision based on that.